# How to Add the displayName While SigningUp using createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I was trying to add the display name to the user immediately after the signup(using createUserWithEmailAndPassword ) and store it in name field in firestore. But when I see  it in firestore it says null, I am completely new to this,

Here is how I trying to do it:

**`UserSignUp.dart`**

```js
class UserSignUp{
  static FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  static signupWithEmail({String email, String password, String name}) async {
    final res =  await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password).then(
          (value) async {
            await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.updateProfile(
              displayName: name,
            );
      },
    );

    final User user = res.user;
    return user;
  }

class UserHelper {
  static FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  static saveUser(User user) async {
    
    Map<String, dynamic> userData = {
      "name": user.displayName,
      "email": user.email,
      "last_login": user.metadata.lastSignInTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      "created_at": user.metadata.creationTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      "role": "user",
    };
    final userRef = _db.collection("users").doc(user.uid);
    if ((await userRef.get()).exists) {
      await userRef.update({
        "last_login": user.metadata.lastSignInTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      });
    } else {
      await _db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).set(userData);
    }
    await _saveDevice(user);
  }
  }
}
```

**

**Signup_screen.dart**

**

```js
class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignupPageState createState() => _SignupPageState();
}

class _SignupPageState extends State<Body> {
  TextEditingController _emailController;
  TextEditingController _passwordController;
  TextEditingController _nameController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _emailController = TextEditingController(text: "");
    _passwordController = TextEditingController(text: "");
    _nameController = TextEditingController(text: "");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Background(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "SIGNUP",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
              width: size.width * 0.8,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: kPrimaryLightColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29),
              ),
              child: TextField(
                controller: _nameController,
                // onChanged: (value) {},
                cursorColor: kPrimaryColor,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    color: kPrimaryColor,
                  ),
                  hintText: "Full Name",
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
              width: size.width * 0.8,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: kPrimaryLightColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29),
              ),
              child: TextField(
                controller: _emailController,
                // onChanged: (value) {},
                cursorColor: kPrimaryColor,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    color: kPrimaryColor,
                  ),
                  hintText: "Your Email",
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
              width: size.width * 0.8,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: kPrimaryLightColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29),
              ),
              child: TextField(
                controller: _passwordController,
                obscureText: true,
                // onChanged: (value) {},
                cursorColor: kPrimaryColor,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Password",
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.lock,
                    color: kPrimaryColor,
                  ),
                  suffixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.visibility,
                    color: kPrimaryColor,
                  ),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              width: size.width * 0.8,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29),
                child: FlatButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 40),
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                  onPressed: ()  async {
                    if (_emailController.text.isEmpty ||
                        _passwordController.text.isEmpty) {
                      print("Email and password cannot be empty");
                      return;
                    }
                    try {
                      final user = await UserSignUp.signupWithEmail(
                          email: _emailController.text,
                          password: _passwordController.text,
                          name: _nameController.text);
                      if (user != null) {
                        print("signup successful");
                        // Navigator.pop(context);
                      }
                    } catch (e) {
                      print(e);
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "SIGNUP",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Main.dart**

```js
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Auth',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {

            UserHelper.saveUser(snapshot.data);
            return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(snapshot.data.uid).snapshots() ,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                  final userDoc = snapshot.data;
                  final user = userDoc.data();
                  if(user['role'] == 'user') {
                    return //;
                  }else{
                    return //;
                  }
                }else{
                  return Material(
                    child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),),
                  );
                }
              },
            );
          }
          return //;
        }
    );
  }
}
```

> but in my firestore the name filled is null

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DvnI.png)

Answer (score 0):

From shared code, I would like to share my understanding and thoughts which might help you to get your solution.

*I know, you are already aware about this and that might be the reason you are storing user's info based on  section 2's callback event.*

**Section 1**

This part of the code will on save user's name on **Firebase Auth** only **not on Firestore**
You can just verify if user's name is updated on firebase auth user's list.

```
UserSignUp -> signupWithEmail -> currentUser.updateProfile
```

**Section 2**

`UserHelper.saveUser` is called based on `authStateChanges`  **not user profile info changes** from Firebase.

So, there are higher probability user's display name will be updated on profile info after this callback..
Hence, user's `displayName` may be `null` while you are saving data on Firestore.

```
MainScreen -> StreamBuilder -> UserHelper.saveUser
```

**Suggestion**

I would suggest you to save user's info after updating the user's display name on profile to Firestore instead of `authStateChanges` event.